# Why does subprocess use a list instead of a string with spaces by default?

Tags: python, subprocess

Why does Python's `subprocess` module expect the arguments as a list by default? Why isn't a string with spaces (similar to what you type into a terminal when running the command normally) the default input? There are plenty of sources explaining how to pass in the space delimited string of the command into `subprocess`, but it's less clear as to why the default isn't the other way around.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TL;DR Using the list bypasses the shell so that you don't need to worry about the shell interpreting a dynamically constructed command line in ways you did not intend.

---

Suppose you have a really simple command: `echo foo`. Here it is, using both a string and a list:

```
Popen("echo foo", shell=True)
Popen(["echo", "foo"])
```

Not much difference yet. Now suppose the argument contains quotes to protect whitespace and/or a shell pattern, `echo "foo   *    bar"`:

```
Popen("echo \"foo   *    bar\"", shell=True)
Popen(["echo", "foo   *    bar"])
```

Yes, I could have used single quotes to avoid needing to escape the double quotes, but you can see the list form is starting to have an advantage. Now imagine I don't have a literal argument for the command, but that it is stored in a variable. *Now* which do you want to use...

This?

```
Popen('echo "%s"' % (x,), shell=True)
```

or this?

```
Popen(["echo", x])
```

If you answered "the first one", here's the value of `x`:

```
x = "\";rm -rf \""
```

The command you just executed was `echo ""; rm -rf/""`. You needed to make sure any special characters in the value of `x` were first escaped before incorporating it into the string you are building to pass to the shell.

Or you just use a list and avoid the shell altogether.

Comment: That's a reason why you or I should prefer the no-shell list version, but not exactly an answer as to why that's the default.

Comment: More efficient (no shell process is started) and more secure isn't enough?

Comment: An additional moral of this story is that echoing strings containing `rm -rf` is probably a bad idea, even when you think you're being careful.

Answer (score -1):

Forget all that I wrote - just read the relevant PEP yourself

https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0324/

===============

My short guess - the no-shell list version is closer to the format that is eventually passed to the POSIX `forking` commands.  It requires less manipulation.  The shell string approach is something of a Windows legacy.

=====================

So you are asking why the `shell=False` case is the default?

> On POSIX, with shell=False (default): In this case, the Popen class
>   uses os.execvp() to execute the child program.  args should normally
>   be a sequence.  A string will be treated as a sequence with the string
>   as the only item (the program to execute).
>
> On POSIX, with shell=True: If args is a string, it specifies the
>   command string to execute through the shell.  If args is a sequence,
>   the first item specifies the command string, and any additional items
>   will be treated as additional shell arguments.

'why' questions tend to be closed because they rarely have definitive answers, or they involve opinions, or history.

I'd suggest studying the `subprocess.py` code.  I see for example a lot of calls to:

```
Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs)
```

It's init is:

```
def __init__(self, args, bufsize=-1, executable=None,
                 stdin=None, stdout=None, stderr=None,
                 preexec_fn=None, close_fds=_PLATFORM_DEFAULT_CLOSE_FDS,
                 shell=False, cwd=None, env=None, universal_newlines=False,
                 startupinfo=None, creationflags=0,
                 restore_signals=True, start_new_session=False,
                 pass_fds=()):
```

As a keyword arg, `shell` has to have some default value; why not False?

I suspect that in the `shell` case it passes a whole string to some code that calls the shell.  In the no-shell case it must pass a list.  But we have to find that code.

There are 2 methods of call the subprocess, one for POSIX and the other Windows.   In the POSIX case it appears to convert the string list, regardless whether shell is True or not  It may be more nuanced than that, but this is the relevant code:

```
        """Execute program (POSIX version)"""

        if isinstance(args, (str, bytes)):
            args = [args]
        else:
            args = list(args)

        if shell:
            args = ["/bin/sh", "-c"] + args
            if executable:
                args[0] = executable
     ....
     self.pid = _posixsubprocess.fork_exec(
                        args, executable_list,...
```

In the windows shell case the args string is combined with `cmd` info:

```
    if shell:
            ....
            comspec = os.environ.get("COMSPEC", "cmd.exe")
            args = '{} /c "{}"'.format (comspec, args)
     hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
                                     # no special security
                                     ....
```

Comment: No, it's more complicated than this.  `shell=True` can be a security hazard.

Comment: And making it non-default reduces that hazard? Who does it protect, the beginner or the expert?